# Zend validators and error messages: addValidator and addErrorMessage

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

If I have a form element that has multiple validators attached to it (3 in this example), how would I use `addErrorMessage` to create custom error messages when each unique validator fails. Is there a way to add a custom message for each validator?

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text()...
$element->....
        ->addValidator(...)
        ->addValidator(...)
        ->addValidator(...)
        ->addErrorMessage()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically it's done per validator error message, not per validator...

```
$element->setErrorMessages(array(Zend_Validate_...::CONSTANT => 'New Message'));
```

But I often prefer to override all of an element's errors to a single

```
$element->setErrorMessages(array('Single Error'));
```

or, if I need it per validator, this works...

```
$validator->setMessages('string error')
```

should override all a validator's errors to a single message.  I could not find this documented anywhere, but it works for me.  Because of this, it may not work for all versions?

To me, the error messaging handling is a bit messy unless you want to override every possible error message, but hopefully one of these solutions works for you.

Cheers

Comment: i have some aditional errors but using the first validation not working

Answer (score 6):

Add your message along with the validator as below.
 Example:

```
->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(0,255,'messages'=>'Cannot be more than 255 chars'))

->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages'=>'Cannot be empty'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Add your message like this

**->addValidator( 'Alpha', true, array( 'messages' => array( 'notAlpha' => "Please enter alphabetic character only in Product name.
") ));**

Add validator message according to your error string

Comment: I like the specified message handling via 'notAlpha'. can you guide me to where I can find more of those identifiers for the rest of validators? thanks anyway :^)

Comment: You find these varibale of error message from its validate file.
go to below path
project/library/Zend/Validate 

select your validate rule,
Here you find list of "const" that is for error message

Answer (score 0):

addErrorMessage('Your Custom Message'); It is also easiest way to print the custom message.

The addErrorMessage is defined inside libraray/zend/Form/Elements.php

Hope it helps!!